# VB6 - Send and Receive SMS Messages without GSM Modem (To use Android Mobile Phone/Device as GSM Modem?)

Tags: android, vb6, sms

There is a requirement for the field force to send SMS Messages for data like Employee Code, Time-in, Time-out, etc.

The SMS message that will be received needs to be parsed and then saved into a database to create reports.

Basically, I have no access to a GSM Modem nor will I be able to procure one in time for the project.

**Query**:

Can an android phone be a substitute for this? (GSM Modem)

**What is needed**:

Create a VB6 application that will capture and parse the SMS Message into the database table. As well as, send SMS Message to the field force personnel the confirmation that the SMS was received or if there are errors on the format.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're looking for a SMS Gateway to use with VB6. First Hit in Google:
http://www.vianett.com/en/developers/api-code-examples/vb-6

First Hit for Sms Gateway free:
http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/

Also, ask your admins if there's already a gateway in use at your company, usually they use one for their nagios or zabbix or alike.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  This is very interesting since this is the first time that have encountered this.

However, I think these kinds of service has a very steep price tag.  Something a small to medium business will most likely shy away from.

Comment: Waoh, thanks for the downvote. All you needed to do was adding a "free" to the google search which you probably never even tried.

Comment: Hmm...  If you are assuming that I did the downvote then you are clearly mistaken.  Heck, I didn't even get why the question got a downvote or am I missing something?